# add_months function in Spark R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a variable of the form "2020-09-01". I need to increase and decrease this by 3 months and 5 months and store it in other variables. I need a syntax in Spark R.Thanks. Any other method will also work.Thanks, Again
In R following code works fine

```
y <- as.Date(load_date,"%Y-%m-%d") %m+% months(i)
```

The code below didn't work. Error says

unable to find an inherited method for function ‘add_months’ for signature ‘"Date", "numeric"

```
 loaddate = 202009
 year <- substr(loaddate,1,4)
 month <- substr(loaddate,5,6)
 load_date <- paste(year,month,"01",sep = "-")
 y <- as.Date(load_date,"%Y%m%d")
 y1 <- add_months(y,-3)
```

Expected Result - 2020-06-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lubridate` package makes dealing with dates much easier.  Here I have shuffled `as.Date` up a step, then simply subtract 3 `months`.

```
library(lubridate)

loaddate = 202009
year <- substr(loaddate,1,4)
month <- substr(loaddate,5,6)
load_date <- as.Date(paste(year,month,"01",sep = "-"))
new_date <- load_date - months(3)
```

`new_date` Output:

```
Date[1:1], format: "2020-06-01"
```